# Specific position for tooltip

Tags: javascript

I have a layer which opens up as a tooltip everytime I hover a button. I simply did that by creating a JS function which displays or hides the layer.

Now, I am not a pro in JavaScript. My problem is the following:  when the button is scrolled towards the top oft he screen I want the tooltip opening below – and if the button is near the bottom of the screen I want the tooltip opening above. Right now I just did it with absolute positioning. But obviously that doesnt do the trick.

Who can help? Thanks!

Comment: a) 11 questions and you have not accepted any answers? Why should anyone help you? b) Why not just use a `title` attribute on your button for a standard browser tooltip?

Answer (score 1):

Absolute position for the tip I think it's the right choice!

When you open it (i.e. when you go over the button), check if its Y offsetTop is <= of the Y median (imaginary) line of the page (window.innerHeight or (IE case) document.body.clientHeight divided by 2).

For example a solution could be (more or less):

**Edited**: [check this fiddle example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/zSDhP/) (set "expand" height to see how it works ;))

**Edited(2)**: Now works on IE too

when the page is scrolled (and you want to maintain the tooltip opened -> you don't use mouseout), you can recheck opened tips and arrange them again

Comment: When I copy your code it doesnt seem to be working. I can see the tooltip, but it doesnt change positions at all. Any ideas?

Comment: @Fiona do you have a running visible example? Did you check the fiddle, does it work as expected?

Comment: No I dont have a running visible example. The fiddle one work well. But after copied on my machine it doesnt work.

Comment: If you want you can send me the code and I will check it as soon as I have 5 free minutes. Meanwhile you can check if the HTML structure is the same, css is Ok, and if doctype is set ;)